# Inversions in the array, what am I getting wrong. Please have a look at the Math/Pseudo code below

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I have been trying to write a pseudo code for the number of inversions.

For this illustration let our array be called mainArray of length n. and also assume that n is an even integer.

From my understanding an inversion in an array is needed when `i<j, mainArray[i] > mainArray[j]`. We then swap places in order to sort this.

Using the merge sort algorithm, once we reach the base case and start merging the two halves (left-half and right-half) the code looks like the following

```
let i = 0, j=0, k=0, inversions = 0
for k in range(0,n-1) 
    if left-half[i] < right-half[j]
       mainArray[k] = left-half[i]
       i+=1
    else
       mainArray[k] = right-half[j]
       j+=1

       //now at this point an inversion has occurred
       //so from my understanding at this point there was only 1 swap? because the program 
       //skipped left-half[i] and proceeded to right-half[j]
       // so my answer was **"Inversions = Inversions + 1"** incrementing by 1 Inversions wherever the **Else-Block is run**. 


       //but in the solution the correct answer is 
       Inversions = Inversions + {(n/2)-i}
```

I don't get this part? **why are assuming that the right-half[j] swaps places with all the remaining elements in the left-half of the array.**  what key-point am I missing here?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that `left-half` and `right-half` is sorted, so if `i<j, left-half[i] > right-half[j]` this implies `left-half[i+1..n/2] > right[j]` too. So we count `Inversions + {(n/2)-i}` to count *all* of the inversions, not just one.

Comment: so if I get this right, taking this following example: let left-half = [1,3,5] and right-half = [2,4,6]. During the merge step when 2 is added to index position 1 of the mainArray. There are two recursions not one? because there are two remaining elements in the left-array? and "2" was added before those two elements (3 & 5)?

Comment: @pi2018 I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "recursions". There is no recursion happening in the code.

Comment: Sorry I meant inversions

Comment: Yes there will be two inversions found so far because 3 > 2 and 5 > 2. Because we know all the rest of the elements after 3 *have* to also be greater than 2 since the array is sorted.